# SearchView as an MenuItem in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I'm implementing an material searchView in fragment menu item . I use the library - https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView as my searchView .
I have implemented as per this and finally my output looks like this :

[image]

I want to take this searchview into the header. How do i acheive it ??

My Code :

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends Fragment{
    MaterialSearchView search_view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Search");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        search_view = (MaterialSearchView) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        search_view.setMenuItem(item);
    }
}
```

activity_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

searchmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/abc_search_hint"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`
in your app Theme. like

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       .......
       .......
       <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: use android default search view

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Extended-ActionBar-Guide here is denials of implementation